# Ionic 2: cordova run android Error (Unmatched closing tag)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, angular, ionic2

When I run `cordova run android` I see the following error:

```
Failed to install 'ionic-plugin-keyboard':Error: Unmatched closing tag: widget
Line: 37
Column: 9
Char: >
    at error (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:347:8)
    at strictFail (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:364:22)
    at closeTag (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:529:5)
    at Object.write (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:948:29)
    at XMLParser.feed (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
    at ElementTree.parse (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:271:10)
    at Object.exports.XML (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:606:13)
    at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/util/xml-helpers.js:123:38)
    at ConfigFile_load [as load] (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigChanges/ConfigFile.js:70:33)
    at new ConfigFile (/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigChanges/ConfigFile.js:47:10)
```

Is there any clue on where to look for the error? I checked the config.xml - it looks fine.

Comment: Did you look at line 37, column 9? Is there a `</widget>` closing tag there that doesn't match with the opening tag?

Comment: In which file? The config.xml is only 34 lines long...and has a `</widget>` closing tag!

Comment: The error is not complaining about a missing `</widget>` tag - it's saying there's something like `<foo><bar></bar></widget>` - where the closing tag doesn't match the opening tag. However, if the line number doesn't match, maybe it's a different file (and I wouldn't know what other file to check, sorry)

Comment: I see! I'll try and do a search on the whole plugin - the other plugins are installing just fine! Thanks anyways - at least I have a better understanding! It seems to be an issue of the plugin..

Answer (score 1):

So I erased and recreated the project with the latest ionic2 cli now and it seems to work. I just had one error complaining about the config.xml now, which could be solved by deleting the spaces after the `</widget>`